# One to One Relationship With Shared not Working at Execution time

Tags: mysql, database, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-one

Im using EclipseLink(JPA 2.0) with MySql and I'm having a problem with something in the model.
I have 2 entities: Delincuente, PerfilFisico. They share the Delincuente's Pk.

The DB is working correctly but when i insert a Delincuente and then the Perfil Fisico,  i tried to show the PerfilFisico of that Delincuente (Using Delincuente.PerfilFisico.), it was just empty. I checked the tables at the DB and everything was ok.

If i run the system again (I'm developing in Netbeans 7.2) and i consult the Delincuente that i just registered on the DB, it shows all the fields and everything is perfect!!

There is the code:

Delincuente.java

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "delincuente")
private PerfilFisico perfilFisico;
```

PerfilFisico.java

```
@JoinColumn(name = "PK_IdDelincuente", referencedColumnName = "PK_Identificacion", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@OneToOne(optional = false)
private Delincuente delincuente;
```

What is wrong, i've been reading for days and i can't figure out which the problem is. Any tips?

As i said it works, but when you are running it and you register a new Delincuente, you have to re-run the System to succesfully complete the consult and see the PerfilFisico

Answer (score 1):

JPA EntityManagers have a first level cache for managed entities, and providers like EclipseLink have a second level cache.  So if you don't maintain both sides of your bidirectional mappings so they are out of sync with the db, it won't show unless you force a refresh, clear the cache or restart.  The app must maintain bidirectional relationships, JPA won't do it for you, as they are meant to be pojos.

Comment: I see.
And how can i force that Refresh?

Comment: see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching for examples on using caching in EclipseLink.  Its better to maintain both sides of your relationship IMO though

Comment: I've tried to set up what u said. Still can't Fix it. Any suggestions

Comment: Tried what exactly?  Are you setting both sides of your relationships when you persist them?